# Relation of percent units in css to window size and/or resolution

Tags: css

Why do I have to set the height of div to 88% instead of 94% – (100% - (3% + 3%) padding) and more importantly, why the body (indicated by its background-color), shows up when I make the window smaller? I have two screens with different resolutions and it behaves the same on both of them. I'd like the space to be filled with div but without vertical scrollbar and it should not matter what the size of the window is...

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 3%; background-color: orange; height: 88%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `padding: 3%` means 3% of the *width* is used for all 4 padding values - in most cases that would be more than 3% of the height - this `div` won't size properly from one screen to the next.

One solution might be to use `box-sizing: border-box`:

(setting box-sizing to `border-box` on an element means the padding and border are included in the dimensions, so we could safely use `height: 100%` with any padding value)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 3%; background-color: orange; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
</div>
```

Comment: Seconding using `box-sizing: border-box` for calculating layouts. Instead of needing to do math like 94% + 3% + 3%, you could use 100% height and 3% padding without modifying the element's size.

Answer (score 0):

the background property is set to the whole inner content
the padding is assigned to the inner content properties,
so you must set margin property instead of padding :)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3%; 
  background-color: orange; 
  height: 88%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```